# Can't append multiple elements when looping through a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm looping through an array. Each iteration, I set the value of a variable to the current index in the array and append it to a div in my HTML. However, only the last index is being appended to the div.

Here's my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < pronouns.length; i++) {
     var para = document.createElement("P");
     para.innerHTML = pronouns[i];
     para.style = "display: inline-block";

     alert(pronouns[i])
     document.getElementById("main").appendChild(para);
     document.getElementById("main").appendChild(input);
     document.getElementById("main").appendChild(br);
}
```

`pronouns` is equal to: `['I','Me','You']`.
Can anyone help?

Comment: input and br are just other elements being added, that are declated outside of the for loop. their values never change.

Comment: `para.innerHTML = pronouns[i];` will assign whatever `pronouns[i]` refers to, *overwriting* the current `innerHTML` of `para`. You probably want `para.innerHTML = para.innerHTML + pronouns[i]`.

Comment: Can you add definition of input and br? I have tested commenting these lines and it output `IMeYou` into div.

Comment: @BenM that shouldn't change much as `para` is a newly created element

Comment: Can you please create a [mre] so we can see the issue and help you debug it? Currently, it doesn't look as though your issues is reproducible: https://jsfiddle.net/3aw510d2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As asked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12730824/13464279) question, the problem is you are using the same child, then is adding only one time.

Check how using this:

```js
var pronouns = ['I','Me','You']
var br = document.createElement("br");
var input = document.createElement("input");

for (var i = 0; i < pronouns.length; i++) {
     var para = document.createElement("P");
     para.innerHTML = pronouns[i];
     para.style = "display: inline-block";

     document.getElementById("main").appendChild(para);
     document.getElementById("main").appendChild(input);
     document.getElementById("main").appendChild(br);
}
```

```html
<div id="main"> </div>
```

It only adds one `br` and one `input`. To solve this you can create the childs into loop and will be added.

```js
var pronouns = ['I','Me','You']

for (var i = 0; i < pronouns.length; i++) {
     var para = document.createElement("P");
     var br = document.createElement("br");
     var input = document.createElement("input");
     para.innerHTML = pronouns[i];
     para.style = "display: inline-block";

     document.getElementById("main").appendChild(para);
     document.getElementById("main").appendChild(input);
     document.getElementById("main").appendChild(br);
}
```

```html
<div id="main"> </div>
```

Or use [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

```js
var pronouns = ['I','Me','You']

var para = document.createElement("P");
var br = document.createElement("br");
var input = document.createElement("input");

for (var i = 0; i < pronouns.length; i++) {
     para.innerHTML = pronouns[i];
     para.style = "display: inline-block";

     document.getElementById("main").appendChild(para.cloneNode(true));
     document.getElementById("main").appendChild(input.cloneNode(true));
     document.getElementById("main").appendChild(br.cloneNode(true));
}
```

```html
<div id="main"> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `input` and `br` nodes you append should be *clones* of the already created nodes. Otherwise every iteration overwrites the previously appended node. Try something like:

```js
const input = Object.assign(document.createElement("input"), {type: "text"});
const br = document.createElement("br");
const main = document.querySelector("#main");
const pronouns = ['I','Me','You'];

for (var i = 0; i < pronouns.length; i++) {
     const para = Object.assign(document.createElement("p"), {innerHTML: pronouns[i] + "&nbsp;"});
     para.style = "display: inline-block";
     main.appendChild(para);
     main.appendChild(input.cloneNode());
     //                     ^ clone the original
     main.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
}
```

```html
<p id="main"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be several solutions to this based on your exact need, but if you want array value as `paragraph` and then `input field` and `br element` after that, simplest is this -

```js
var pronouns = ['I','Me','You'];

for (var i = 0; i < pronouns.length; i++) {
  var para = document.createElement("P");
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  var br = document.createElement("br");

  para.style = "display: inline-block";
  para.innerHTML = pronouns[i];

  document.getElementById("main").appendChild(para);
  document.getElementById("main").appendChild(input);
  document.getElementById("main").appendChild(br);
}
```

```html
<div id="main" />
```